# Como llamar a una api externa en c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webservice, api

Quiero saber cual seria la forma correcta para llamar a una API EXTERNA en c# asp.net, ya sea llamando a la api mediante un web service o por algún otro método.
Desconozco como llamar a la API e implementarla en mis propio proyectos

O que me orientaran como hacer el llamado de una api en C#, se los agradecería mucho

Comment: Podrias usar HttpWebRequest con los using System.Net

Comment: perfecto gracias, usare HttpWebRequest para hacerlo, no es necesario crear un Web Service para el llamado de la API?

Comment: lo puedes llamar directamente y parseas las respuestas de la API, las respuestas pueden ser en formato Json, ya esas respuestas puedes parcearlas desde C# o Ajax u otra que deses utilizar